# The HPBW of a helical antenna

Tags: antenna, antenna-theory, math, circular-polarization

can someone tell me what are the formulas of HPBW for a helical antenna?

I've searched a lot and I saw that there are two different formulas of HPBW for the helical antenna,

this one,

$$ \mathbf{(HPBW)} = [\frac{52}{C} \sqrt{\frac{\lambda^2}{NS}}] $$

and this one,

$$ \mathrm{HPBW} \simeq \frac{52}{\frac C\lambda \sqrt\frac{NS}{\lambda}} \mathrm{degrees} $$

so what is the difference between both ?

Comment: One of them is wrong by an exponent in $\lambda$. Otherwise, with applying the basic calculus rules for division and roots, they are identical.

Comment: Hello Abdullah, and welcome to this site! :-)

Comment: The Gain is extremely sensitive to the error in winding geometry from an ideal helical shape thus the latter equation from Kraus leads to higher gain than best effort by a few dB using $$HPBW = k \lambda ^{\dfrac{3}{2}}$$

Comment: Hello Abdullah, I replaced your equations in .png files with MathJax equations.  Here's a [quick introduction to MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 2):

Kraus says

$${52}\over{{C\over\lambda} \sqrt{n{S\over\lambda}}} $$

Which is your second equation.

Be aware that this only holds for a narrow range of diameters and spacings: $0.8<{C\over{\lambda}} <1.8$ ; $12<\alpha<14$ and $n\ge4$